# Cannot return from controller in jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have 2 dropdown menus. I’m trying to get results from MySQL database in the second dropdown (education_subject) depending from the selection in the first (education_level). I have the following code in my JS file:

```
jQuery.ajax({

    type:"POST",

    url: url,

    data: data,

    dataType: "json",

success: function(results){

    results = jQuery.parseJSON(results);

    console.log(results);
```

where:

```
data: { id: [level id from the first dropdown] }

url: 'programs?tmpl=json&r=subjectsChosen'
```

and 'subjectsChosen' is the name of the function in my controller. Here is my controller:

```
public function subjectsChosen() {

    $result = $this->db->setQuery("SELECT id, title FROM k_education_subjects WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id")->loadObjectList();

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I always get NULL result in console.log(results).

Any suggestions in my problem?

Comment: what is returned at your controller end for $results ?

Comment: I cannot echo $result cause my form waits ajax's response.

Comment: after ajax call is made from client  to your controller, debug your controller code and see what is the value of $results ?

Comment: I don't know how to debug my controller, but I think that I cannot see $result, because I run this script via Jumi component in Joomla site layout.